# Collator - different collation rules in Android and Windows for the same US locale

Tags: java, android, collator

If I run the code in Eclipse / Windows, I get different results than if I run the code in Android.

After importing the jar library into Android project, the Collator is giving me different results for dash and forward slash characters.

I was expecting similar behavior.

Can somebody explain this?

```
package java.text;

    Collator myCollator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.US);
```

Result:

```
myCollator.compare(" ", "-")
```

In Windows:
-1
In Android:
1

```
myCollator.compare("/", ".")
```

In Windows:
-1
In Android:
1

The Windows results seem to be correctly sorted according to this table here:

https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/Corticon/index.html#page/corticon/character-precedence-3a-unicode-and-java-collator.html

But the results in Android are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there are differences in the collator for the Android environment and Windows Java SDK.